# How do I edit a cover page for my thesis like this template?

Tags: covers

I'm trying to dive under this incredible world of non-WYSIWYG. So, for my first main challenge I need to write my master's thesis with LaTeX. And I found some difficulties at the very beginning of my work: the cover page. I need to customize the cover page like this model (it's the mandatory model for our thesis in my university): [image]

I need the university logo to be within the dotted retangle. I tried to fit it there without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us your attempt by providing a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)?

Comment: Hello, Pedro! `:)` I tried to find out the reference to this cover page format in the Unicamp guidelines, but the layout I found is slightly different. Do you have a link to this specific part?

Comment: Pedro, the minimal working example is very important here, since we don't know the class you're loading -- e.g., if you're working with the [**`abntex2`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/abntex2) bundle, you should redefine the `\imprimircapa` macro.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new here, I didn't know I had to post my MWE, here goes my preamble:
http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/9237/iok4.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can encolose the title page in a `titlepage` environment so the document class deals with it in a proper way.

Then you can set the distances between text blocks in a relative way to each other (by using the `\stretch` command), so if you are required to change the paper size (university policies with respect to thesis formatting can be very annoying) they still keep the same proportion on the page.

You can also define picture sizes relative to document parameters, by defining lengths as a number multiplying predefined constants, say defining `width` as a multiple of `\textwidth`. Be sure to use a vectorial picture so it does not suffer loss of quality due to resizing (and also makes for smaller file sizes). You can find the UNICAMP logo in several formats [here](http://www.unicamp.br/unicamp/a-unicamp/logotipo/download) (**Beware:** the eps version has some gibberish code written after the postscript code. Get rid of it otherwise LaTeX won't like it).

You can fine-tune the margins further by using commands from the `geometry` package.

So a full example of a `titlepage` would be

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

...

\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{your-university-logo}

\centering
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\Large{Your Name}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\LARGE{\textbf{Your Thesis Title}}

\vspace{\stretch{2}}
\Large{Your City\\Date}

\end{titlepage}
```

[image: Example of a titlepage]

Comment: Hey @Sir Whiteout it was so obvious! I put the _\includegraphics_ within the _\centering_ command and it always appeared in the top middle. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! You can have even more control over the positioning of the logo by using either a `minipage` environment or the `wrapfig` package, but in this case it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first approach to what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\geometry{margin=3cm} %declare margins as they shold be in the doument itself
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=3cm,right=3cm,left=3cm,bottom=2cm,includefoot}
{\color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2cm}}\par
\begin{center}
{\color{red}Modelo CAPA...}\par
\vspace{1cm} %or any other space you like
{\Large (Enter your name here)}\par
\vspace{2cm} %as above
{\huge (Enter your title here)}\par
\vfill
{\Large CAMPINAS\\[.5\baselineskip]
2012}
\end{center}
\restoregeometry
%From here you can start the rest of your thesis
\end{document}
```

To include you actual image just replace the line

```
{\color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2cm}}\par
```

with `\includegraphics[scaling]{picname}`. Uncomment line 5 after declaring the margins of your actual thesis body (I assumed the margins you gave, are for the titlepage only), *and* drop the 'showframe' option of `geometry` when you feel confident about the layout.

Comment: Hello @Ruben, just by replacing the {\color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2cm}}\par command and inserting my \includegraphics... after compiling the image wasn't at the left corner, but in the top middle. This is my preamble: [Preamble](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/iok4.png/)

Comment: @PedroNakasu: This is easy to fix. Just put the `\includegraphics` invoce outside of the `center` environment and everything will be like desired. (The `center` environment does actaully align its content in the center of the page). And of course, you don't need to put the image into a group, i.e. just eliminate the pair of braces around it. They are needed with the `\large`, etc. commands for some reasons. But this does not belong to this question. (ATM I can't find a post explaining it on this site, but google will help or you might jut ask a new question, if you don't find it either.)

Comment: Oh yes, I figured it out just now, the problem was indeed the _\includegraphics..._ inside the _\begin{center}_ command thank you!

Comment: I've just removed the pair of brackets around the image. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-50,-50)%adjust these values to place the graphic
\includegraphics{dummy.jpg}
\end{picture}
\begin{centering}
\vspace{5cm}%adjust as needed
\vfill
my name here
\vfill
\vspace{5cm}%adjust as needed
Title
\vfill
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but wouldn't this make more sense as a redefinition of `\@maketitle`?

Comment: Didn't know if the title text wasn't repeated or no inside, so tried to make it simple since the OP didn't make an MWE.

Comment: Hello @WillAdams , I've tested your solution, but after compiling it, a black-colored square has appeared instead of my picture (and I figured out you misstyped "figure" in the _\begin{picture}_ part). The black square was followed by a (0,0) part that I think is due to the _\begin{figure}(0,0)_ command. Here goes my preamble: [preamble](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/iok4.png/)

Comment: I don't see the word ``figure'' in my code. The black coloured square is created by the demo option for graphicx. Replace dummy.jpg w/ your graphic.

Comment: I suppose it was "figure" and not "picture", am I wrong? Anyway, the problem was the \includegraphics... inside the \begin{center} command. I removed the [demo] option, thank you @WillAdams